# Visual Calendar for Java

Tags: java, calendar

i want to write a simple programme which should be like this:
On the first Window there should be 6 Buttons when I click on one Button a new window with a VISUAL Calendar should appear. Does java deliver any standard for visual calendars or do I have to write it all from the start?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no package within the JDK that does this for you. This site is also not fornlibrary recommendations. You either need see if one exists for yourself, or attempt to write it yourself. This post is currently too broad. Come back with some code, and we can help you out

Comment: ok thx,,, well i think i will try with JXDatePicker

Comment: if it doesnt it would mean that i have to draw a calendar all by myself? This would mean i need functions for correct days for each month and year etc. Im really suprised that there is no swing element for a calendar

Comment: Well Java does have `Calendar`, it just doesn't use GUI to display things. I'm sure there are many examplea online of java calendars. Also, like I said before, if you get stuck, come back and we'll be glad to help (as long as your question is formatted nicely and abides by the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). Try to include code with your next question aswell